# SQLITE : near from syntax error:

Tags: sqlite, syntax-error

I stucked on following error if i'm executing this SQLlite command:

```
Error: near "FROM": syntax error
```

I check code of the query few times but i cannot able to locate error.

Could somebody tell me what is wrong in my code?

Thanks for any help.

**SQL query:**

```
SELECT d.date AS DATE,
       IFNULL(DIALS_CNT, 0) AS DIALS_CNT,
       IFNULL(APPT_CNT, 0) AS APPT_CNT,
       IFNULL(CONVERS_CNT, 0) AS CONVERS_CNT,
FROM
  (SELECT DATE('2014-01-01', '+' || (t4.i*10000 + t3.i*1000 + t2.i*100 + t1.i*10 + t0.i) || ' days') date
   FROM
     (SELECT 0 i
      UNION SELECT 1
      UNION SELECT 2
      UNION SELECT 3
      UNION SELECT 4
      UNION SELECT 5
      UNION SELECT 6
      UNION SELECT 7
      UNION SELECT 8
      UNION SELECT 9) t0,
     (SELECT 0 i
      UNION SELECT 1
      UNION SELECT 2
      UNION SELECT 3
      UNION SELECT 4
      UNION SELECT 5
      UNION SELECT 6
      UNION SELECT 7
      UNION SELECT 8
      UNION SELECT 9) t1,
     (SELECT 0 i
      UNION SELECT 1
      UNION SELECT 2
      UNION SELECT 3
      UNION SELECT 4
      UNION SELECT 5
      UNION SELECT 6
      UNION SELECT 7
      UNION SELECT 8
      UNION SELECT 9) t2,
     (SELECT 0 i
      UNION SELECT 1
      UNION SELECT 2
      UNION SELECT 3
      UNION SELECT 4
      UNION SELECT 5
      UNION SELECT 6
      UNION SELECT 7
      UNION SELECT 8
      UNION SELECT 9) t3,
     (SELECT 0 i
      UNION SELECT 1
      UNION SELECT 2
      UNION SELECT 3
      UNION SELECT 4
      UNION SELECT 5
      UNION SELECT 6
      UNION SELECT 7
      UNION SELECT 8
      UNION SELECT 9) t4) d
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT substr(m.date, 1, 10) AS my_date,
          COUNT(m.ID) AS 'DIALS_CNT',

     (SELECT COUNT(*)
      FROM dialed_calls subq
      WHERE subq.call_result = 'APPT'
        AND substr(m.date, 1, 10) = substr(subq.DATE, 1, 10)) AS 'APPT',

     (SELECT COUNT(*)
      FROM dialed_calls subq
      WHERE subq.call_result = 'CONV_NO_APPT'
        AND substr(m.date, 1, 10) = substr(subq.DATE, 1, 10)) AS 'CONV_NO_APPT',

     (SELECT COUNT(*)
      FROM dialed_calls subq
      WHERE subq.call_result = 'CANNOT_REACH'
        AND substr(m.date, 1, 10) = substr(subq.DATE, 1, 10)) AS 'CANNOT_REACH'
   FROM dialed_calls m
   GROUP BY my_date) t ON d.date = t.my_date
WHERE d.date BETWEEN '2014-09-30' AND '2014-09-20'
ORDER BY d.date;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple typo;

```
IFNULL(CONVERS_CNT, 0) AS CONVERS_CNT,    <-- extraneous comma
FROM
```